# cannot configure glowroot with elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, glowroot

I'm trying to attach glowroot for elasticsearch, but in glowroot logs I can see these errors:

> 2023-05-25 08:38:01.133 ERROR o.g.a.s.o.g.c.util.ScheduledRunnable - access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "findMBeanServer")
> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "findMBeanServer")
> at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:485)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1068)
> at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)
> at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkPermission(MBeanServerFactory.java:414)
> at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:361)
> at org.glowroot.agent.util.LazyPlatformMBeanServer.findAllMBeanServers(LazyPlatformMBeanServer.java:263)
> at org.glowroot.agent.init.GaugeCollector.runInternal(GaugeCollector.java:147)
> at org.glowroot.agent.shaded.org.glowroot.common.util.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:44)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> 2023-05-25 08:38:01.226 ERROR o.g.a.i.PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache - access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/portal/scripts/glowroot-0.14.0-dist/glowroot/agent-ESGLOW/tmp/preload-some-super-types-cache" "write")
> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/portal/scripts/glowroot-0.14.0-dist/glowroot/agent-ESGLOW/tmp/preload-some-super-types-cache" "write")
> at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:485)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1068)
> at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)
> at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:842)
> at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:223)
> at org.glowroot.agent.impl.PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache.appendNewLinesToFile(PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache.java:221)
> at org.glowroot.agent.impl.PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache.writeToFile(PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache.java:173)
> at org.glowroot.agent.impl.PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache$1.run(PreloadSomeSuperTypesCache.java:152)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

OS is Centos 7.9.2009
Elasticsearch 7.17.6 with bundled java 18.
Tried it also on my local machine with windows and getting same exceptions.
Any tips how to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't seem ES related, the error is `access denied to file /portal/scripts/glowroot-0.14.0-dist/glowroot/agent-ESGLOW/tmp/preload-some-super-types-cache`, so it's more like a Java security misconfiguration